# How to update useReducer states in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get the item from localStorage and pass it too useReducer State.

When i switch from one button to another button states  is not updating. My `initialState` did update but `states` does not update

my `initialStates` and `states` on console.log both the values differ. `states` always stores the previous values of selected button Genid item value and `initialStates` stores the current selected values of selected button Genid item value but the main problem is did not update to useReducer states part

```
const Played = ( {Genid} ) => {
    console.log("Played page ")
    console.log("*************************************************")
    console.log(Genid)
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(Genid)))

    const initialState = {
        DATA: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(Genid)) || [],
        isFetching:  localStorage.getItem(Genid) ? true : false,
        hasError: false,
    }
    console.log(initialState);


    const [states, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    console.log(states)
```

Comment: can you create a reproducible demo. It does work for me when I try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue in your code was simple, the initialState wasn't populated in reducer because the displayid was undefined initially and then was set to `ditto`

The reason there is this behavior is because in `Veritcal` component you `setDisplayId` and that effect run ater initial render and by that time the undefined displayId is already being used by the `Horizontal` component

Now, there were other issues with your code too. You were updating sessionStorage with `response.data.payload` but there was no key as `payload` in `response.data`

Also `Movement` component is mapping on `state.data` but that is an object. Instead you need to map on `state.data.abilities`

Changed code snippets below

Movement.js

```
const Movement = ({ states }) => {
  console.log(states);
  return (
    <div>
      {states.data &&
        states.data.abilities.map(ability => <div>{ability.ability.name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movement;
```

---

Horizontal.js

```
  console.log(displayid);
  const initialState = {
    // data: displayid? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(displayid)): [],
    // isFetching: displayid && sessionStorage.getItem(displayid) ? true : false,
    // hasError: false
  };

  const [states, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  // console.log(states);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (displayid && !sessionStorage.getItem(displayid)) {
      console.log(displayid);
      axios
        .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${displayid}/`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.data);
          dispatch({
            type: "First",
            payload: response.data
          });
          console.log(response.data);
          sessionStorage.setItem(displayid, JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          dispatch({
            type: "Second"
          });
        });
    } else if (displayid && sessionStorage.getItem(displayid)) {
      // populate data from localStorage
      const localData = {
        data: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(displayid)) || [],
        isFetching: sessionStorage.getItem(displayid) ? true : false,
        hasError: false
      };
      dispatch({ type: "POPULATE", payload: localData });
    }
  }, [displayid]);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mestorf-61dxm?file=/src/Horizontal.js)

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri thankyou so much i was stuck in this part from last two days

Comment: Hi @Shubham Khatri can i use state for managing cache for the same steps if i don't want to use third patry btowser i.e. sessionStorage or localStorage. This is my general question.

Comment: You can use localState. The only problem with it is that it won't persist on page refreshes